# Protocol error (Page.getResourceContent): Agent is not enabled. (Puppeteer)

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

I'm having a problem running this code.

```js
const client = await page.target().createCDPSession();
    const content = await client.send("Page.getResourceContent", {
      frameId: String(page.mainFrame()._id),
      url,
    });
```

I got this error:

```
{
  level: 'debug',
  message: 'Protocol error (Page.getResourceContent): Agent is not enabled.',
  name: 'ProtocolError'
}
```

PS: in the old version of puppeteer i used the code below and it worked fine.

```js
const content = await page._client.send("Page.getResourceContent", {
      frameId: String(page.mainFrame()._id),
      url,
    });
```

Anyone know why??

i haven't figured out a solution for this and i couldn't understand what this error means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message "Agent is not enabled" has nothing to do with the HTTP User-Agent header but refers to an agent within chrome that needs to be enabled in order to retrieve page contents.

The term "agent" is a bit misleading since the [protocol documentation](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/) speaks about domains which need to be enabled in order to debug them (the term "agent" refers to the way this is implemented in Chrome internally, I suppose)

So, the question is which domain does need to be enabled in order to access the page contents? In hindsight it is quite obvious: the Page domain needs to be enabled as we are calling a method in this domain. I only found this out after stumbling over this [example](https://github.com/cyrus-and/chrome-remote-interface/wiki/Take-page-screenshot), though.

Once I added the Page.enable request to script to activate the Page domain, the error message disappeared.

My solution:

```js
      const client = await page.target().createCDPSession();

      await client.send("Page.enable");       
      await client.send("DOM.enable");        
      await client.send("Network.enable");    

      const content = await client.send("Page.getResourceContent", {
      frameId: String(page.mainFrame()._id),
      url,
    });
```